# Is it possible to send a link to a Slack conversation directly to the Slack app?

Tags: slack

When using Slack on MacOS, I typically keep two clients open at once: the usual desktop app, and a package that's used from within Emacs.  The latter does 90% of what I need, but I sometimes need to hop over into the desktop app.  The Emacs package can produce a URL link to a particular Slack chat, in the form

```
https://mycompany.slack.com/archives/ABCDEFGHI/p9988776655443322?thread_ts=1234567890.123456&cid=AB1CDEF23
```

I can send this link to my browser (Firefox), which then somehow opens the chat in the regular app.  A little circuitous, but all good so far.

Originally Firefox would take under a second to hand off the chat to Slack, but at some point, something changed and it now takes several seconds instead, which is irritating.

Is there some way to send a link directly to the Slack app?  Or, failing that, to reduce the time it takes Firefox to open the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Slack via the "Contact Us" button in the app's "Help" feature.  I received a prompt reply suggesting that I clear the cache in both Firefox and Slack.  I cleared Firefox's cached data for the slack.com domain, then Slack's cached data via `Help > Troubleshooting > Clear Cache and Restart`.  After that, opening Slack message links in Firefox was back to sub-second response times.

Comment: > then Slack's cached data via Help > Troubleshooting > Clear Cache and Restart

This doesn't seem to be an available option in the browser version of Slack anymore

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are methods to link users to such entities in a [Slack Deep Linking Reference](https://api.slack.com/reference/deep-linking).

Most likely you should provide a link like in [Opening a direct message with your app or bot section](https://api.slack.com/reference/deep-linking#app_or_bot): `https://slack.com/app_redirect?app={APP_ID}`; or use a `slack://` in your URI protocol as in [Open an App Home section](https://api.slack.com/reference/deep-linking#open_app_home): `slack://app?team={TEAM_ID}&id={APP_ID}`. You can obtain Team ID (typically starting with `T**`) and Application ID (`A**`) from workspace browser URL and a Configuration page of an application.

Comment: This page doesn't seem to help.  Only the "Link to messages" section near the bottom looks relevant, and that just links to a "chat.getPermalink" page which describes a URL that looks exactly like the one I provided originally.

Comment: The `thread_ts`/`cid` link you provided is a link to a message in a thread where root message is `thread_ts` parameter and `cid` is a channel id,and `p**` is a ts to a message you want to open without dot.However,the browser Slack Web Client will perform three undocumented `/api/users.prefs.get` calls that returns undocumented object `desktop_deeplink_signals`,after that it will offer open a link in desktop app (or redirect to a desktop app),so looks like that is how the web client works,so you could try to generate `slack://` links directly to open desktop client first instead of browser one.